# Access and update textview from another activity android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, layout-inflater

I'm working on a project, where i send lists from one user to the other, I'm using Firebase to do that.

So here is my code, and what i tired to do.

```
public class GuideMyTour {
    TextView received_tourTitle;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tours_item_list, null, true);

    received_tourTitle = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tour_list_tv_TourTitle);
```

where *tours_item_list.xml* is only a layout and i want to update the "TextView" that it have which is *tour_list_tv_TourTitle*

```
guideDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                received_tourTitle.setText(ListTitle);
                Log.d("TAG", "GuideMyTours onChildAdded: ListTitle: " + ListTitle);
                }
```

I'm sure that *ListTitle* is not null, because this is what it says in the Logcat, but it doesn't seem to update the text for some reason, it still shows the default *hint*

Comment: What's the issue then?

Comment: the text doesn't update, i edited the question

Comment: Did you check that ListTitle is not an empty string?

Comment: yes, it givee the right valute, its an adapter btw

Comment: Run the update on the main thread.

Comment: How do i run the update? i didn't understand you sorry..

Comment: @m0skit0 Firebase callbacks are called on the main/UI thread, so updating views is safe to do from directly within the `onChildAdded` callback.